# OK response even with the wrong password?

Tags: python, request, httpresponse

I am trying to write a script that'll let me interact with my router without opening up the browser. I wrote the following script.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
username = input("Enter username ")
password = input("Enter Password ")

with requests.Session() as c:
    url = "http://192.168.1.2" #+url   make it dynamic later
    print(url)
    username = username
    password = password
    r = c.get(url)
    print(r)
    login_data = dict(userName=username, pcPassword=password,next='/')
    c.post(url,data=login_data, headers={"Referer": "http://www.techruse.com/"})
    page = c.get('http://192.168.1.2//userRpm/WlanStationRpm.htm')
    print(page.content)
```

every time I run the code and enter my correct password this is the response I get.

```
<Response [200]>
b'<body><script language="javaScript">window.parent.document.cookie="Authorization=;path=/";\nwindow.parent.location.href = "http://192.168.1.2";\n</script></body></html>\n'
```

and with the wrong password the response is exactly the same. I understand that  code means The request was full filled (source : 
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html) either I have the wrong understanding of the term or maybe I am not authenticating at all. Can someone please explain this to me? thank you.

Comment: You are probably not authenticating at all. The response is a simple redirect to the home page. Do not always rely on status code, the response can help too.

Comment: I figured that must be the case, can you check my code and see what's wrong with it? @masnun

Comment: I am not sure how your router authenticates. There could be some hidden fields for CSRF protection as well. Some cookies may be? I guess you will have to carefully examine the request using the devtools on your browser and ensure the behavior in code. I would rather recommend using Selenium with a headless browser like PhantomJS.

Comment: all right I'll try to use Selenium, thank you for pointing me in the direction.  @masnun