# grabbing cookies through python

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I have been trying to authenticate to my router for a long time now, and have been utterly unsuccessful, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451135/ok-response-even-with-the-wrong-password) is my question here. What I am trying to do is to authenticate to my router and grab the session cookie. As after I login into my router using the browser the URL displayed becomes `http://192.168.1.2/DQOPHPHAILDUSWQC/userRpm/Index.htm` the string between userRpm and the router url itself I am assuming is the Cookie. And then request the URL again with the session Cookie in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookielib, it will automatically handle the cookies for you.
You can load the initial URL and then get the content of the cookie like this:

```
import cookielib, urllib2

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

data = opener.open("initialURL")
# print(data)
print(cj)
```